# How do I used a for loop to apply the paste0 function onto many dataframes?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataframes:

```
hh02 <- c("exp_02", "m1_02", "m2_02")
```

I have tried to create a new variable called `hhid` in each item in `hh02` by doing the following:

```
library(dplyr)

for(i in hh02){
  formula_hhid02 <- as.formula(paste0(i$tinh02, i$huyen02, i$xa02, i$diaban02, i$hoso02))
  i$hhid <- formula_hhid02
}
```

However I am getting an error message saying: Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Is there a way I can create a new variable called `hhid` , preferably in dplyr language. Thank you.

Comment: As a side question: why are you using `as.formula()` here? It seems to me just the `paste0(...)` would suffice here.

Answer (score 0):

###### problem

While assuming `exp_02`, `m1_02` and `m2_02` are your dataframes, keep in mind that

```
hh02 <- c("exp_02", "m1_02", "m2_02")
```

does not actually put those dataframes together in a list; it just creates a vector with three strings in it. So you can't access the dataframes through these strings directly, as attempted in the question.

An obvious idea would be to put the *actual* dataframes in a list, but also this way we cannot modify them, because the results are stored in `i`, which is a **copy** of the original dataframe, not a reference to it:

```
# doesn't work:
hh02 <- list(exp_02, m1_02, m2_02)
for(i in hh02){
  i$newcolumn <- "hello world"
}
```

###### solution

We can use the functions `get()` and `assign()` to retrieve or assign the value of objects by string names, respectively:

```
# create some example data frames
ex1 <- mtcars
ex2 <- iris
ex3 <- PlantGrowth

# create a list of data frame names as string
hh02 <- c("ex1", "ex2", "ex3")

# loop over string names
for(i in hh02){

  # get a value from dataframe 'i':
  df <- get(i)
  
  # modify
  df$newcolumn <- "hello world"
  
  # store
  assign(i, df)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When you are looping over hh02, each iteration of `i` is just the string `"exp_02"` or some other, corresponding to the iteration. You want to put you dataframes into a list, as such:

```
df_list <- list(
  exp_02 = exp_02,
  m1_02 = m1_02,
  m2_02 = m2_02
)
```

Then you can for loop the elements of the list, which would be each data.frame.

```
for(df in names(df_list)){
  x <- df_list[[df]] #Copy current iteration of data.frame
  x$hhid <- paste0(x$tinh02, x$huyen02, x$xa02, x$diaban02, x$hoso02) #Add column
  df_list[[df]] <- x #Overwrite data.frame in list.
}
```

Now without any reproducible example, i cannot validate that this will overwrite/append the $hhid column to the data.frame in the list, but this should be enought to get you going i hope.

Comment: This only modifies `df` inside the loop; which is a copy of the data frames inside `df_list`. After the loop has run, both `df_list` and all three original data frames will be unmodified.

Comment: Yes, as i point to in the last paragraph.

Comment: I've edited the answer so that it now overwrites.

Answer (score -1):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
```

Example data

```
exp_02 <- tibble(data = rnorm(10),
                 A = rnorm (10))

m1_01 <- tibble(data = rnorm(10),
                A = rnorm (10))

m1_02 <- tibble(data = rnorm(10),
                A = rnorm (10))

# A tibble: 10 x 2
      data       A
     <dbl>   <dbl>
 1  0.187   1.78  
 2 -0.895   0.969 
 3  0.360  -0.0876
 4  0.489   0.410 
 5  1.84    2.32  
 6 -1.65    0.948 
 7  0.0524 -1.44  
 8  1.56    3.13  
 9  0.410   0.690 
10  1.36    1.22
```

Put them into a list

```
hh02 <- list(exp_02,
             m1_01,
             m1_02)
```

Create a new column.
Example take the column `A * 2`

```
imap(hh02, ~ bind_cols(.x, hhid = .x$A * 2))

[[1]]
# A tibble: 10 x 3
      data       A   hhid
     <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 -0.164   1.48    2.95 
 2  0.344  -1.33   -2.66 
 3 -1.99   -0.307  -0.614
 4  1.19   -0.458  -0.916
 5 -0.836  -0.0525 -0.105
 6  1.19   -1.22   -2.44 
 7  1.81   -0.349  -0.698
 8 -0.0463  0.444   0.888
 9 -0.261  -0.663  -1.33 
10 -0.0405  0.708   1.42 

[[2]]
# A tibble: 10 x 3
      data       A   hhid
     <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 -1.30    0.279   0.559
 2  0.0888 -0.969  -1.94 
 3  1.48    0.444   0.889
 4 -1.25    0.656   1.31 
 5  1.80   -0.512  -1.02 
 6 -0.121  -0.0720 -0.144
 7 -0.469  -1.64   -3.29 
 8  1.43   -1.17   -2.34 
 9  0.555  -0.393  -0.786
10 -0.139   0.241   0.483
```

Comment: A little extra explanation: the core of this answer is the function `purrr:imap()`, which applies a function to each element in a vector/list and returns the result. It doesn't save the results; you have to do that yourself.